# Windows 10 Taskbar: Avoid Grouping/Combining of Windows if application was started using different shortcuts

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, shortcuts

I've got two shortcuts on my desktop for the same application.
Shortcut 1 opens the application without any additional start parameters, while shortcut 2 does have several start parameters.
However both point to the same path, to the same .exe, and I cannot have two installations on the same machine.
No matter which shortcut is used, the application windows have got the same Application User Model ID, therefore they are grouped/combined by 7+ Taskbar Tweaker.

It is possible to avoid the windows being grouped given that there are two different shortcuts?

Comment: By the way, you can choose in 7+ Taskbar Tweaker to never group items of your Application User Model ID at all - use Taskbar Inspector with right click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tool called [win7appid](https://code.google.com/archive/p/win7appid/), which can change an Application User Model ID of the app that is launched through the given shortcut file.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable grouping altogether, you can do that by pressing `Win+I` (thats an 'i') > `Personalization` > `Taskbar` > `Combine taskbar buttons`.  And set it to **Never**